# Should you call HttpRequest.Abort()?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, webrequest, httpwebresponse

**IG.NORE PLS I THRASHED THIS AND CAN'T DELETE**

This is my code -

```
static void SendViewLoop()
{
    HttpWebRequest httpRequest;

    while (true)
    {
        //do stuff here

        //start
        for (int i = 3; i > 0; i--)
        {
            try
            {
                //create request
                httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("URL");
                //httpRequest stuff here like headers, timeout, etc

                //start get and dispose
                using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse()) { }

                //sleep
                Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));
            }
            catch { continue; }
        }

        //do stuff here
    }
}
```

I’m trying to request something forever, though it changes every request, but I am unsure on how to or if I should dispose httpRequest. Is it required to abort httpRequest, as in is it doing something during that 2 minute wait, is it taking up unnecessary memory or possibly something else?

Comment: https://www.thomaslevesque.com/2018/02/25/better-timeout-handling-with-httpclient/

Comment: I am confused.  You are calling the same endpoint 3 times, two minutes apart each time, but in your description, you say you are calling it forever.  What are you doing with the data that comes back?